# Allowing Foreign Key to be Null

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ssms

I'm trying to create a relationship between two tables where one column in TABLE A is the foreign key for a column in TABLE B. However, there is one row in TABLE B that is currently null in that column and it's giving me an error. However, from Googling the issue, the general consensus seems to be that null is an acceptable value in a foreign key field. But I'm still unable to create this relationship in SSMS due to the error message. How can I bypass this?

Error:

```
Unable to create relationship 'FK_RELATIONSHIP'. 
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY 
constraint "FK_RELATIONSHIP". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASE", 
table "TABLE A", column 'COLUMN 1'.
```

SQL Code as requested:

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TABLEA]    Script Date: 10/02/2012 17:44:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLEA](
[COLUMN1] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TABLEA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[COLUMN1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TABLEB]    Script Date: 10/02/2012 17:44:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLEB](
[COLUMN1] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
[COLUMN2] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TABLEB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[COLUMN1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? Are you sure you're creating the FK in the right direction?

Comment: What is the command you're using to create the FOREIGN KEY.  Null-ability of the column in question should be decided by the CREATE TABLE command, not the CONSTRAINT command.

Comment: Error: "Unable to create relationship 'FK_RELATIONSHIP'.  
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_RELATIONSHIP". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASE", table "TABLE A", column 'COLUMN 1'."

If it's in the wrong direction, should it not give an error stating that the field must be unique?

Comment: I'm using a GUI in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), not a command...

Comment: Are you sure it's the fact that a column is NULL, and not that there is a value in the TABLE A column that doesn't match any column in TABLE B?  That would report the same error message as well.  Can you provide data dumps of your two tables edited into the post or as a pastebin link?

Comment: I have tried changing the column to "NONE" from null and adding a "NONE" row to TABLE A and the error disappears...

Comment: Would you be allowed to use Database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts to generate SQL code for your database and data, and upload it somewhere we can access?

Comment: I can probably do it, but this would be without the foreign key relationship?

Comment: This will sound silly, but are you sure that `NULL` you are seeing is actually null and not content of nvarchar?

Comment: The few times I've tried to use that UI, it's confused the heck out me and I have got things bass ackwards. Your none to null scenario doesn't prove you haven't as you added None to table A. See if yo can add a an other record to TableB with something that doesn't exist in TableA.

Comment: Agree with @Nikola.  As you can see here, `NULL` is allowed in a foreign key field: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab003.  However, if you use the string `'NULL'` as the value, I generate the same error message you are getting: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab003.  If you want to take this a step further, install the [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/), and use the Generate Insert Scripts wizard to generate SQL for the exact contents of your tables and edit it into your post.  You can also use "Generate Change Script" option to include the SQL for your proposed fk_relationship.

Comment: Oh my god you guy are right... It turns out when I was editing the rows using the GUI, I simply deleted the contents of the entire cell leaving it empty where I actually needed to type NULL into the cells. Seems like a really stupid mistake but I didn't think a completely empty cell could be different from NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles here with the same question. An empty cell is not the same as a NULL cell. Empty cells are '' not NULL!

Answer (score 2):

```
update TABLEA set COLUMN1 = NULL where COLUMN1 = '';
update TABLEB set COLUMN2 = NULL where COLUMN2= '';
```

If you changing your "NULL" values to none and it works, it might just be that there's an empty string or a hidden character in there.

Try recreating your FK after that.